# Cartesian product of set of empty sets with a non-empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $B=\{0,1\}$ and $C=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ what is the cartesian product of $B\times C$?

Comment: As long as you're not looking _inside_ the empty set, it is just a mathematical object like any other. So $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ are put into the pairs that make up the cartesian product in exactly the same way that $0$ and $1$ do.

Comment: (Fun fact: In _axiomatic set theory_ where everything is a set and numbers don't exist in their own right but must be simulated using sets, the sets that are usually used to represent the numbers $0$ and $1$ are exactly $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$).

Answer (score 1):

$$B\times C=\bigl\{(0,\emptyset),(1,\emptyset),(0,\{\emptyset\}),(1,\{\emptyset\})\bigr\}$$

Comment: Thank you so much,Sir

Answer (score 1):

The Cartesian product of two sets $A,B$ is defined as: 
$$A×B:=\{(a,b) | a∈A, b∈B\}.$$

So in your case it is: 
$$B×C = \{(0,­­∅), (0, \{­∅\}), (1,­­∅), (1, \{­∅\})\}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much,Sir